# Obtain Unique Client IP or MAC address on Intranet Meteor/Javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor, ip-address, mac-address, intranet

I am searching for a way to avoid using a login system for a website in my company's intranet. I've been attempting to find either the client IP, MAC address, or any other unique identifier. I'm trying to avoid using cookies. I know that client IP and MAC address can be spoofed, but I still want to try using it.

I've seen a lot of other similar posts, especially ones using this.connection.clientAddress, however, unfortunately I haven't been able to get them to work. It only works when I use it for localhost. The moment I attempt to use it on the server, I'm unable to get a unique IP address probably because of all the proxies in front of the server. I've been trying to use the HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT environment variable to guess how many proxies there are and potentially get a unique value, but I have been unsuccessful. Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this problem?

**edit**
Additional info: I'll be attempting to use the unique info to prevent a specific user from performing a certain action on my site more than once over a set period of time (probably 24 hours).

Comment: Use authentication (go through your AD or LDAP server) and keep an audit log. It will be simpler, more reliable, and more usable than deriving tokens from the system.

Comment: I do use LDAP to compare certain things, but I'm confused as to what you're suggesting. What unique field could I input into LDAP to identify the user? Could you please elebaorate?

Comment: Their username? User Id? Your intranet identity provider will already have unique identifiers for each principal, so just use that rather than inventing a new system.

Comment: The problem is that I am attempting to avoid any form of login. In order for me to figure out their user ID or username, they would have to enter it somewhere. Unless there is a way to obtain that information without any form of prompt? We need to do this because we are tasked to make the site as simple as possible and avoiding a login is one of the main features.

Comment: You can do that without a prompt, if you use some form of yubikey or client certificate. Tie the identifier on the key/cert to your existing records (like FreeIPA and SSH certificates).

Comment: I'm looking into it, but it's rather complex. Might take me a few hours to figure out. Also, have you by chance ever considered using websockets to get IP?

Comment: I can't say I've ever tried to get a client's IP, by socket or otherwise. Our applications all sit behind haproxy balancers and my IP will change if I'm on wifi or docked, so client IPs are usually rather meaningless (servers are a different story, since they are typically static).

Answer (score -1):

I think your best bet is to use a Server Sided Technology to handle this rather than Client side. Client Side Javascript wont send you any IP information directly. In PHP you can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` In order to recive an IP address, however, as you say, It can be spoofed very easily and unless the machine is statically assigned an IP address could change frequently and become unreliable.

Comment: When I used "this.connection.clientAddress", I placed it in the server side code. Did i use it incorrectly? And in my research earlier, I did find a command similar to the one you offered. In meteor I wrote: this.connection.remoteAddress. Unfortunately, I was never able to get a result except "undefined" when using it. When I used clientAddress, it gave me a unique address, however only on localhost. Do you know why this could be? And any theories as what I could have done wrong?

Comment: Also how did your solution bypass all the proxies in front of the server?

Comment: Meteor is a client sided framework, What Server Sided System are you using? PHP, ASP, Django?

Comment: Ahh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I'm using MongoDB. That is the default for meteor.

Comment: No. MongoDB is your database, its not your backend server language. What are you using to serve your pages, NodeJS perhaps?

Comment: As far as I understand, it's just plain javascript. This would be rather embarrassing if I misunderstood again :(

Comment: Not to worry, You could be Using NodeJS as your server-side code, but you should really find out if your unsure, A good place to start is how do you serve the information. i.e do you host it in a linux webserver, like apache? IIS Express for Windows. WAMP?